# How to import play.db.ebean.Model.Finder?

Tags: playframework

How can I import play.db.ebean.Model.Finder ? I'm using Play framework.
[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8Exu.png) 
And here is the [FAQController.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kptj0.png) So in my opinion I have to import play.db.Model.Finder because public static Finder can not work without it. Only problem is how to import?

Comment: Please post the code you are using, Play version and your build.sbt deps

Answer (score 0):

The class `com.avaje.ebean.Model` in the error message hint that you use Play 2.4.*. `play.db.ebean.Model` was deprecated in that version - https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24.

You need to replace `play.db.ebean.Model.Finder` with `com.avaje.ebean.Model.Finder`